# How can I join a list of strings in specman?

Tags: string, join, specman

I have a list that I want to print:

```
foo: list of string;
```

I want to create a string `bar` that is the concatenation of the elements of `foo`.  In Perl I would do:

```
$bar = join " ", @foo;
```

The only way I can think of to do this in specman is:

```
var bar: string = "";
for each in foo {
    bar = appendf("%s %s", bar, it);
};
```

This seems like it would have very poor performance, because it copies `bar` onto itself for each element in `foo`.  Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a dedicated function for this:

```
str_join(list: list of string, separator: string) : string
```

I'm sure `help str_join` will give you the details. There are also other useful functions like `str_match`, `str_split` which you may like.

As an additional hint, maybe you should print yourself the *e Language Quick Reference*, see http://www.cadence.com/Community/blogs/fv/archive/2009/06/19/send-us-suggestions-for-updating-the-e-specman-quick-reference-card.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I stumbled across the `to_string()` method.  I can use:

```
var bar: string = foo.to_string();
```

This is the equivalent of Perl's:

```
$bar = join "\n", @foo;
```

If I want to use spaces I can use:

```
var bar: string = str_replace(foo.to_string(), "\n", " ");
```